# How to permanently set the environment variables for OpenVino

Tags: openvino

I am setting up OpenVino on my system and I get this form the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-Windows#next-steps):

> (Optional): OpenVINO toolkit environment variables are removed when you close the Command Prompt window. As an option, you can permanently set the environment variables manually.

But there is no information is available on what are the required environment variables and what value they should be set.

I need to know the list of environmental variable needed by OpenVino and the value that they should be set to. I know how to set them in Windows (using GUI or Setx).

Comment: Hi, how did you solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables need to be set are given in the setupvars.bat file present at "path_to_computer_vision_sdk_directory\bin".

But I will give a general idea on the paths that need to be set - 
Set the following **System variables** in your Environment Variables

1. Variable name: *INTEL_CVSDK_DIR*
   Variable value: *path_to_computer_vision_sdk_directory* i.e. 
   *C:\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_version_number*, in case you have the cvsdk setup at the default path for installation
2. Variable name: *OpenCV_DIR*
   Variable value: *%INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\opencv\cmake*
3. Variable name: *OPENVX_FOLDER* 
   Variable value: *%INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\openvx*
4. Variable name: *InferenceEngine_DIR*
   Variable value: *%INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\share*
5. Variable name: *HDDL_INSTALL_DIR*
   Variable value: *%INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\external\hddl*
6. Now edit the "*Path*" variable under System Variables to include the following values - 
   *%INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\opencv\x64\vc14\bin
   %INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\openvx\bin
   %INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Release
   %INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Debug
   %HDDL_INSTALL_DIR%\bin*

You also nee to set the "*PYTHONPATH*" to *%INTEL_CVSDK_DIR%\python\python_version%*