# INFERENCE_ENGINE_LIB not set error in Cmake

Tags: cmake, openvino, raspberry-pi4, movidius

I'm trying to run the gender_age sample (https://github.com/movidius/ncappzoo/tree/master/apps/gender_age)
in my raspberry pi 4 with intel movidius Myriad X VPU and I have an error

I follow the tutorial https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/get-started-with-neural-compute-stick until the Next Steps: The ncappzoo title here is my error

```
Intel OpenVINO environment is already set!
(mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake ..; make;)
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
INFERENCE_ENGINE_LIB
    linked by target "gender_age" in directory /home/pi/Documents/ncappzoo/apps/gender_age

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/Documents/ncappzoo/apps/gender_age/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/pi/Documents/ncappzoo/apps/gender_age/build »
make[1]: *** Pas de cible spécifiée et aucun makefile n'a été trouvé. Arrêt.
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/pi/Documents/ncappzoo/apps/gender_age/build »
make: *** [Makefile:68: compile_cpp] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The CMake file for this example depends on the OpenVino environment variables. Assuming you have installed OpenVino, using it typically requires the [OpenVino environment variables](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000033440/boards-and-kits/neural-compute-sticks.html) to be set, either in the current command prompt, or permanently in your System environment variables. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571419/3987854) answer describes, you can set each of these individually, or run the environment variable script before proceeding with your `cmake` command:

```
> C:/path/to/your/openvino/opencv/setupvars.bat
```

After running this in your command prompt, the command `cmake ..` should be able to access these environment variables (particularly `INTEL_CVSDK_DIR`) and succeed in generating the buildsystem. Then, you can compile the example with `make`.